# Resize cursors are missing in `NSCursor`

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, nscursor

I'm writing a resizable view in SwiftUI on macOS. Drag its edge can change its size. I'd like to show according cursor when dragging different edges. So I looked up [Apple NSCursor documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor), however, I cannot find resize cursors like those generally used in system as shown below.

How can I get those cursors? I attached my code below in which drag the `Divider()` to resize the cyan rectangle. Hovering on that `Divider()` will change the cursor.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("InspectorHeight") var inspectorHeight = 200.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            
            Color.cyan
                .frame(width: 100)
                .frame(height: CGFloat(inspectorHeight))
            
            Divider()
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
                
                .onHover { inside in
                            if inside {
                                NSCursor.resizeUpDown.push()
                            } else {
                                NSCursor.pop()
                            }
                        }
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { drag in
                            inspectorHeight = max(100, inspectorHeight - Double(drag.translation.height))
                        }
                )
            
        }
        .frame(height: 600, alignment: .bottom)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please add a [mcve] showing the problem

Comment: What kind of window are you creating? When I move the cursor to the edge of a window in my macOS SwiftUI app I get exactly the cursors you have in your image by default.

Comment: @AshleyMills I attached it in the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm not meaning the whole app window. I know it's system behavior. I'm going to change the cursor manually. I attached some code to reproduce my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system cursors you're looking for don't exist, so you'll have to create custom ones, which you should be able to approximate using SFSymbols, e.g.:

```
NSCursor(image: NSImage(systemSymbolName: "arrow.up.and.down", accessibilityDescription: nil)!, hotSpot: NSPoint(x: 8, y: 8)).push()
```